# Select via Jquery Buttons and manipulate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <div id="numbers">
        <button>7</button>
        <button>8</button>
        <button>9</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
        <button>6</button>
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button class="colspan">0</button>
        <button>,</button>
    </div>
    <div id="operators">
        <button>/</button>
        <button>&larr;</button>
        <button>*</button>
        <button>C</button>
        <button>-</button>
        <button>+</button>
```

I am looking for a solution, that make this easier.
I want that I can set by jquery the buttons an ID and Class.

How to do that?
With $('#numbers').append does not work it.

Comment: Can you explain more? Question is not very clear

Comment: What are you asking? How to give each button a unique ID programmatically?

Comment: I need to give via jQuery the all buttons a other ID

Comment: What do you mean *'other ID'*? A random one? One according to a particular pattern? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var numbers = [7,8,9,4,5,6,1,2,3];
var ops = ['/','*','C','-','+'];
var count
numbers.forEach(function(num){
    $("#numbers").append("<button id=" +num+ " class=" +num+ ">"+num+"</button>");
});
ops.forEach(function(val){
    $("#numbers").append("<button id=" +val+ " class=" +val+ ">"+val+"</button>");
});
```

Then add CSS to group buttons in groups of 3 like you want.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e4bxr/1/)**

And if you want to add numbers from button text, then do this:

```
$("#numbers").children("button").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id","no"+$(this).text());
    $(this).attr("class","no"+$(this).text());
});
$("#operands").children("button").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id","op"+$(this).text());
    $(this).attr("class","no"+$(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e4bxr/3/)**

Comment: Thats perfect, but I have an Problem, check out my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mskQL/

now it is the double of the buttons

Comment: Can I do tomorrow I havnt 15 Repu, 
Today I have accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#numbers').children("button").addClass("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you want to give each button a unique "id", this code generates ids for the children of `#number` with the pattern of "no1" , "no2" , etc. and for `#operators` "op1" , "op2" , etc.

```
var id=1;
$('#numbers').children('button').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id','no'+id);
    id++;
});
id=1;
$('#operators').children('button').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id','op'+id);
    id++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass()` to give class name to a particular element.

You can use `attr("key","value")` method to provide the id.

```
$("#numbers button").each(function () {
    var obj = $(this);
    obj.addClass(obj.text());
    obj.attr("id", obj.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like below:

```
$("#numbers button").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("class-name");
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).text()"); 
    //if you want to set the id equals the button text
});
```

For operators just change `$("#numbers button")` to `$("#operators button")`..